# Python Extract words only

Tags: python, nltk

Currently I have been using this function to extract only valid words for English only strings and Unicode strings:

```
s = """\"A must-read for the business leader of today and tomorrow."--John G. O'Neill, Vice President, 3M Canada. High Performance Sales Organizations defined the true nature of market-focused sales and service operations, and helped push sales organizations into the 21st century"""
t = 'Life is life (I want chocolate);&'
w = u'Tú te llamabas de niña Concepción Morales!!'

def clean_words(text, separator=' '):
  if isinstance(text, unicode):
    return separator.join(re.findall(r'[\w]+', text, re.U)).rstrip()
  else:
    return re.sub(r'\W+', ' ', text).replace(' ', separator).rstrip()
```

It seems to have issues with last names and apostrophes, any suggestions?
It returns for s:

```
 A must read for the business leader of today and tomorrow John G O Neill Vice President 3M Canada High Performance Sales Organizations defined the true nature of market focused sales and service operations and helped push sales organizations into the 21st century
```

which when I tokenize it results in single characters.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Since you use NLTK, why not use nltk.WordPunctTokenizer() or some other standard tokenizer?

Comment: WordPunctTokenizer  seems to return similar results: word_tokenizer.tokenize(s)
['"', 'A', 'must', '-', 'read', 'for', 'the', 'business', 'leader', 'of', 'today', 'and', 'tomorrow', '."--', 'John', 'G', '.', 'O', "'", 'Neill', ',', 'Vice', 'President', ',', '3M', 'Canada', '.', 'High', 'Performance', 'Sales', 'Organizations', 'defined', 'the', 'true', 'nature', 'of', 'market', '-', 'focused', 'sales', 'and', 'service', 'operations', ',', 'and', 'helped', 'push', 'sales', 'organizations', 'into', 'the', '21st', 'century']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it's a Treebank tokenizer that you want:

```
from nltk.tokenize import TreebankWordTokenizer
tokenizer = TreebankWordTokenizer()
tokenizer.tokenize(s)
#['``', 'A', 'must-read', 'for', 'the', 'business', 'leader', 'of',
# 'today', 'and', 'tomorrow.', "''", '--', 'John', 'G.', "O'Neill",
# ',', 'Vice', 'President', ',', '3M', 'Canada.', 'High', 
# 'Performance', 'Sales', 'Organizations', 'defined', 'the', 'true', 
# 'nature', 'of', 'market-focused', 'sales', 'and', 'service', 
# 'operations', ',', 'and', 'helped', 'push', 'sales', 
# 'organizations', 'into', 'the', '21st', 'century']
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can use `spacy`

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')
s_tokenized = [t.text for t in nlp(s)]

# ['"', 'A', 'must', '-', 'read', 'for', 'the', 'business', 'leader', 'of',
#  'today', 'and', 'tomorrow', '."--', 'John', 'G.', "O'Neill", ',', 'Vice',
#  'President', ',', '3', 'M', 'Canada', '.', 'High', 'Performance', 'Sales',
#  'Organizations', 'defined', 'the', 'true', 'nature', 'of', 'market', '-',
#  'focused', 'sales', 'and', 'service', 'operations', ',', 'and', 'helped',
#  'push', 'sales', 'organizations', 'into', 'the', '21st', 'century']
```